# How to generate url from boto3 in amazon web services

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a Bucket in s3 and I am trying to pull the url of the image that is in there.

I am using boto3 and boto3 doesn't seem to have an implemented generate url method.

They have a core method, that generates url like this,

```
import botocore.session

session = botocore.session.get_session()
client = session.create_client('s3')

presigned_url = client.generate_presigned_url(
    'get_object', Params={'Bucket': self.bucket_name, 'Key': self.key})
```

One thing I am forced to do is, I have to send the parameters along with each request using session object. And the above method does not allow me to set the session variables (ie .. aws credentials)

The closest I can get is this

```
session = Session(aws_access_key_id='342342342342', aws_secret_access_key='3434234322', region_name='us-east-1')
    s3 = session.resource('s3')
    object = s3.Object('my-dev-bucket', 'amazonKeyString')
    print object.get()["Body"]
```

This gets me amazon s3 object which is an object called

```
botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7ffaff8cef50
```

Can I get a url of the image this way?

Comment: Check out [this issue thread](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/110) on the boto3 github.

Comment: Monkpit, I already had that tried, the only thing with this method is, I cannot set session variables in the parameters. This generates url, but it will not look for session variables that I give in the code.

Comment: You can set those parameters when you create the [boto3 client](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.client)

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to this. In the PHP SDK you can use ObjectURL. But I can't seem to find this in boto3

Comment: Your question is confusing to me. Are you trying to (1) generate a pre-signed URL, or (2) trying to generate a 'normal' URL to the object, or (3) asking a question about passing credentials?

Answer (score 82):

Able to get results and did not face any issues in getting the signed URL.
I used the default session since my aws creds were stored locally in "~/.aws/credentials" file and my default region is set as needed ~/.aws/config

```
import boto3
s3Client = boto3.client('s3')
s3Client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params = {'Bucket': 'www.mybucket.com', 'Key': 'hello.txt'}, ExpiresIn = 100)
```

If you need to pass params for Session, import boto3.session and create custom session

```
import boto3.session
session = boto3.session.Session(region_name='eu-central-1')
s3Client = session.client('s3')
```

Comment: This work but when the session expires the url wont work even when the expire time is not yet reached

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `aws configure` command, you can pass the credentials directly like this and generate the public URL.

```
def generate_public_url(bucket_name, file_name, aws_region, aws_key_id, aws_secret, timeout=300):
    #if not object_exists(bucket_name, file_name):
    #    raise Exception(f"0 or many items found in bucket '{bucket_name}' with key '{file_name}')")
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'),
                             region_name=aws_region, aws_access_key_id=aws_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret)
    url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
        ClientMethod='get_object',
        Params={
            'Bucket': bucket_name,
            'Key': file_name
        },
        ExpiresIn=timeout  # seconds
    )
    return url
```