# Temporary keys for AWS access

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm writing a Python code to put files into S3 bucket.
I'm connecting using key and Id.

I also need to work on something to get temporary key and id to connect and do the same.

I saw various options like assume_role, API calls etc.
But, its pretty confusing for me.

My requirement - 
My python code (running on my machine) should generate temporary key and id to make a S3 connection (using boto).

Please help

Comment: you could also consider a presignedurl for s3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549254/how-to-generate-url-from-boto3-in-amazon-web-services shows an example.

Comment: See a python example using boto to get temporary credentials here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html

Comment: does your machine is an ec2 instance? then you can assign a role to the instance and aws-sdk will acquire temporary credentials by itself (using metadata services)

Comment: @MichaelConard I saw that page. It says - _The calls to AWS STS AssumeRole must be signed with the access key ID  and secret access key of an existing IAM user ...._ .   But that is not the case for me. I'm just running a Python script in my local machine

Comment: @gusto2 I'm running the script in a local machine. Not an EC2 instance.

Comment: `generate temporary key and id to make a S3 connect` at the end you need to authenticate and authorize somehow to get any access to non-public resources.  So you could 'assume role' or create a pre-signed url. Assuming role can be done by other aws keys or cognito (by social network login). You cannot get any temporary access without having any access