# How to create a downloadable URL for an object (JSON file) in a S3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download, boto3

I have an object saved in a s3 bucket. I want to create a downloadable URL for that object. I used `generate_presigned_url`, as:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

json_url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
    Params={'Bucket': <bucket_name>, 'Key': <json_file>}, ExpiresIn=86400)
```

But, when I click on the provided url, I recieve the following error:

```
<Error>
    <Code> SignatureDoesNotMatch </Code> 
    <Message> The request    signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.    Check your key and signing method. ... 
...
</Error>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you checked if the bucket + key really exists?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate url from boto3 in amazon web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549254/how-to-generate-url-from-boto3-in-amazon-web-services)