# How to generate S3 presigned URL with boto3 resource instead of client

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I trying refactor application that using `s3 = boto3.resource('s3')` (what is [resource](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#service-resource)) as S3 instance.

But only [`Client`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#client) class has the [`generate_presigned_url`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_url) method. So, how can I get presigned URL with `resource`?

In the internet many [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33698531/13946204) and [examples](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html) how to get presigned URL with `client` but nothing with `resource`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the client associated to the resource this way:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
url = s3.meta.client.generate_presigned_url(...)
```